# Adding other views to UIButton

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I want to add some views to a `UIButton`. For example multiple `UILabels`, `UIImages`, etc.
One I add those views, they do not get the touch events. How can I pass the touch events to `UIButton`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of each of the `subviews` you added to your `UIButton` to `NO`.